# Docusaurus 2 How do i add a react component for a feedback form to appear on each page

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus

I'm trying to add a simple Feedback form. I have seen several written as a React component. Where/how would I put this React component so that it would show, ideally on the bottom of each topic page, in my Docusaurus configuration files?  Or how are other people doing this, in Docusaurus, for their documentation websites.

Answer (score 1):

you could use MDX as one approach, you could also develop a plugin using the available lifecycle APIs, for example:

- If you can inject scripts in the `<head>` you can use the `injectHtmlTags` lifecycle API as demonstrated in [docusaurus-plugin-hubspot](https://github.com/stackql/docusaurus-plugin-hubspot); or
- To add elements to the DOM you can use the `postBuild` lifecycle API as demonstrated in [docusaurus-plugin-structured-data](https://github.com/stackql/docusaurus-plugin-structured-data)

Comment: I'm a newbie to writing my own components, etc. And I am just starting with MDX. Do you have or is there any sample MDX code that does this, or has some of the functionality?

Comment: It's basically combining JSX with markdown, have a look at the example at https://github.com/stackql/fullstackchronicles.io/blob/main/src/blog/2022-06-24-converting-google-discovery-docs-to-openapi3-specs/index.md

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding js using [injectHtmlTags()]:(https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/plugin-methods/lifecycle-apis#injectHtmlTags)

This is the plugin i wrote to implement it.

```js
module.exports = function (context) {
  return {
    name: "feedback-plugin",
    injectHtmlTags() {
      const { siteConfig } = context;
      const { baseUrl } = siteConfig;

      return {
        preBodyTags: [
          `
          <script>
            function Feedback() {
                 let myDiv = document.body
              let button = document.createElement('button');
             
                 myDiv.appendChild(button);;
              let span = document.createElement('span');
              let img = document.createElement('img');

              span.textContent = "Feedback";
              span.classList.add("feedback-span");
              button.appendChild(img);
              button.appendChild(span);

              img.src = \`${baseUrl}img/icon_feedback.svg\`;
              img.alt = "Feedback";
              img.width = "24";
              img.height = "24";

              button.classList.add("feedback");
              img.classList.add("feedback-img");

              button.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

              function handleClick() {
                // handleClick logic
            }

            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
              Feedback();
            });
          </script>
          `,
        ],
      };
    },
  };
};
```